# Can this example have been done using row space instead of column space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can this example be done using row space instead of column space?  I have tried but I am new so don't know if I am doing it correctly, doesn't seem right to me.  I tried expressing the given vectors as rows in the matrix instead of columns.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can indeed.  When you find the row space of a matrix, you are finding a basis for the subspace spanned by the row vectors.  Likewise, when you find the column space of a matrix, you are finding a basis for the subspace spanned by the column vectors.  Therefore, you have some freedom as to whether you want to plug the vectors into a matrix as its rows or its columns.

What I am saying is summed up nicely by the following equality:  $R(A) = C(A^T)$.  Note that $R(A)$ denotes the row space of $A$ and $C(A)$ the column space.

Personally, I think finding the row space is faster and easier than finding the column space, so I would opt for plugging the vectors in as rows in a matrix.  Then, a basis for the span of your set of vectors will be the set off all rows which have at least one nonzero element when the matrix has been row-reduced.

Comment: Do I need to transpose the matrix to find the column space then transpose the back to obtain row space? Or do I just rref with the row vectors?

Comment: First, plug the 5 vectors in as rows in your matrix.  Next, get your matrix in rref.  Your basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ will be the set of nonzero rows in rref.

Comment: Will it be the set of nonzero rows in the reduced row matrix? or do I need to see which rows are leading ones, then the basis will be those rows from the original matrix?

Comment: In general, you can take your rref rows to be the basis.  But the question in your post asks for a set of the original vectors themselves.  In this case, you'll have to keep track of which rref rows correspond to which rows in the original matrix.  So yes, you will unfortunately have to see which rows are the leading ones and so forth.

Comment: Will the answers be related? Should the basis for the column space be the transpose of the basis for the row space?

Comment: I get different vectors

Comment: The basis for the column space will be the basis for the row space of the transpose matrix.  As for why you get different vectors, I'm not sure.  One explanation is that, if there is only one linearly dependent vector in that set of 5, then any 4 you choose will be a spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^4$.